# Grunt Exclude Files from dot directories

Tags: gruntjs

I have tried a number of suggestions from Stackoverflow on how to do this, but I can't get them to work. The following excludes the first two files, but does not exclude the nginx files.

```
cwd: 'server',
src ['**/*','!app.js','!config/local.env.js','!config/local.env.sample.js','!routes.js','!.ebextensions/02Nginx.sub.yml','!.ebextensions/02Nginx.config'],
dest: '/',
expand: true
```

I have tried other combinations:

```
'!**/01Nginx.config'
```

I have added 'dot:true'. Nothing prevents that file from going to the server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Second file selection below the first was overriding my selection. Simple enough.